# How can I know whether Outlook is configured or not programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I want to know how can I know whether Outlook is configured or not using c# in winforms?

I found something on this 
http://www.outlookbanter.com/add-ins-outlook/94961-out-check-whether-outlook-configured.html

but don't think it's relevant.

The above link shows approach using registry.
I want to know is there any other way except inspecting registry?

Comment: Perhaps check to see if an OST file is present for the user.

Comment: I doubt. this wont solve my problem. Because what if someone has installed Outlook, configured email account and later deleted email account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check following link

[How to detect whether Outlook is configured on machine using Regis](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/detect-whether-outlook-configured-machine-using-regis-t3719105.html)

As described here, you can perform following check from registry entry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
Messaging Subsystem\Profiles
```

If you find any folder inside this 'Profiles' folder, then the Outlook is
configured for the current user.

Comment: Keep in mind that Outlook 2013 stores profiles in a different location: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles

Comment: One other caveat: there seem to be situations where there are profiles under that key, but when run, Outlook prompts the user with the profile/configuration wizard (meaning it's not _really_ configured).  This can arise, for example, after removing an existing profile.

Comment: @dmitry-streblechenko, Is this path(HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outloo‌​k\Pro‌​files) applicable for MS outlook 16 as well ? or should i use HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Pro‌​‌​files?

Comment: Yes. That is where Outlook 2016 stores the profiles.